# SharePoint refiners does not work after setting Append Text To Query property of Search Core Result web part

Tags: enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

I have created my own search result page with OOB search web part. Everything works as expected.

I have to restrict search with some additional properties so I set "Append Text To Query" property of Search Core Result Web Part and it works perfectly fine.

But when I go to second page of result, refiners shows incorrect count.

for e.g.

total result count is 27

1st Page Refiners shows 27 count

2nd Page Refiners shows 17 count (which is incorrect)

3rd Page Refiners shows 7 count (which is incorrect)

Also refineries are not working if I set fixed query. So if I set fixed query and clicks on any refiners it will always gives the same result coz fixed query overwrite refiners.

*Note: I am not using FAST search*

Answer (score 1):

Refiner count is not acurate in SharePoint Search **before SP2013** - you need deep refinement for this, only available in FAST Search for SharePoint 2010.

> **Deep Refinement** – SharePoint Search only performs a shallow
>   refiner which only allows refinement for the first 50 results in the
>   original query. FAST provides deep refinement which is based on
>   statistical aggregation of managed property values within an entire
>   result set. Because FS4SP provides a deep refiner, the exact count of
>   documents in refiners.
>   http://www.astaticstate.com/2011/01/part-1-fast-for-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I completely agree with the refiners issue. But I am talking about different issue. Refiners has a property named "Accuracy Index" and its default value is 50 which can be set maximum of 500. So upto 500 documents it will give you the correct result. In my case I don't have more then 100 documents. So everything is working fine things does not works on second page when I set "Append Text To Query" property of Core Result Web Part.

Also can you please let me know whether this deep refinement is a web part provided by FAST?